# How to read a FreeRTOS trace dump

Tags: embedded, trace, dump, freertos, rtos

I'm just starting to learn FreeRTOS and have set up the Posix/Linux simulator on my laptop. The Blinky demo works fine but the Full demo breaks after around 5000 ticks with the error `Error:  StreamBuffer - tick count 50000`. The Demo file produces a trace dump when you exit the application but so far as I can see it is completely unreadable. It appears as seemingly random text characters as if I have the wrong encoding or an incorrect baud rate (if I was using a physical device). I can only assume that the dump files are not supposed to be viewed as a normal text file but I cannot find this in the documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That is almost certainly a false positive error that will be due to running so many self monitoring tests at the same time - some of which assume one or more of their test tasks is the only task running at the highest priority.  The trace comes from the Percepio tool, see https://www.freertos.org/trace

Comment: Aren't the demo tasks supposed to run without showing any errors? Also, this still doesn't answer the question of how to read the actual dump.

Comment: Open the dump in the trace tool as per the link in my original answer.

Comment: Is there no free tool to inspect the dump, I'm an academic user so I can get a free license but it seems weird that you have to pay